# Displaying groups having max number of occurence

Tags: mysql, sql

`t_table` looks like:

```
+-----------+---------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| pk_IdLoan | fk_IdCar| fk_IdCustomer| fk_Source_Agency | fk_Destination_Agency | RentalDate | DeliveryDate | Cost |
+-----------+---------+--------------+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I wrote a query:

```
(SELECT fk_IdCustomer, MONTHNAME(RentalDate) AS Month, YEAR(RentalDate) As Year, COUNT(*)
FROM t_loan
GROUP BY fk_IdCustomer, Month, Year);
```

which results in

```
+---------------+-------------+------+----------+
| fk_IdCustomer | Month       | Year | COUNT(*) |
+---------------+-------------+------+----------+
| 1             | July        | 2016 | 3        |
| 1             | November    | 2017 | 1        |
| 1             | September   | 2016 | 7        |
| 5             | May         | 2016 | 1        |
| 6             | January     | 2016 | 1        |
| 6             | September   | 2017 | 2        |
+---------------+-------------+------+----------+
```

Now I want to get these months and years for each customer which result in highest `COUNT(*)`, f.e.:

```
+---------------+-------------+------+----------+
| fk_IdCustomer | Month       | Year | COUNT(*) |
+---------------+-------------+------+----------+
| 1             | September   | 2016 | 7        |
| 5             | May         | 2016 | 1        |
| 6             | September   | 2017 | 2        |
+---------------+-------------+------+----------+
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: oh boi, i edited my question. i really feel that some people here feel extreme pleasure for downvoting brand new questions without any intent for providing advice or help.

Comment: I am still not able to understand why 2nd row is there in the result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai because it's different customer (fk_IdCustomer).

Comment: Nothing wrong with hedonism.

Comment: i can see only frustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit painful in MySQL, which doesn't support CTEs or window functions.  One method is:

```
SELECT fk_IdCustomer, MONTHNAME(RentalDate) AS Month,
       YEAR(RentalDate) As Year, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM t_loan l
GROUP BY fk_IdCustomer, Month, Year
HAVING cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM t_loan l2
              WHERE l2.fk_IdCustomer = l.fk_IdCustomer
              GROUP BY MONTHNAME(RentalDate), YEAR(RentalDate)
              ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
              LIMIT 1
             );
```

Note:  If there are duplicates, you will get all matching values.